# Error when trying to convert nested for loop to Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to convert a nested for loop to java 8 streams.

**Loop implementation**

```
private Set<String> getAllowRolesFromInheritedPolicy(String userId, List<Policy> allowedPoliciesThisCustomer) {

    Set<String> allowedRolesThisUser = Sets.newHashSet();

    for (Policy policy : allowedPoliciesThisCustomer) {
        Map<String, Role> roles = policy.getRoles();
        for (Role role : roles.values()) {
            if (role.getUsers().contains(userId)) {
                allowedRolesThisUser.add(role.getRoleName());                   
            }
        }
    }
```

In the code `role.getUsers()` returns `List<String>`.

**Stream Implementation**

I am trying to change the for loop into java 8 streams :

```
Set<String> allowedRolesThisUser = Sets.newHashSet(allowedPoliciesThisCustomer.stream()
                                       .map(policy -> policy.getRoles().values())
                                       .filter(role -> role.getUsers().contains(userId))
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

But compiler says:

```
error: cannot find symbol : .filter(role -> role.getUsers().contains(userId))
symbol:   method getUsers(), location: variable role of type Collection<Role>
```

`Role` has the function `getUsers`, `Collection<Role>` does not. What should I do to make this conversion correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Hide the fact that role has a collection of users and expose a method hasUser(userId)..

Comment: Could you provide a SSCCE (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions) to make it easier for us to provide solutions?

Comment: Added a SSCCE in my solution with a unit test to prove it works :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution**

```
private static Set<String> streamImplementation(final String userId, 
  final List<Policy> allowedPoliciesThisCustomer) {

  return allowedPoliciesThisCustomer.stream()
    .map(Policy::getRoles)
    .map(Map::values)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .filter(r -> r.getUsers().contains(userId))
    .map(Role::getRoleName)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

**Explanation**

When you get the values in the map, you need to flatten the map. This is done in the following 2 lines

```
.map(Map::values)
.flatMap(Collection::stream)
```

This ensures that the type `Role` is carried forward correctly.

**Full [SSCCE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22754/225167)**

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static java.util.Arrays.stream;
import static java.util.function.Function.identity;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet;
import static me.karun.Policy.policy;
import static me.karun.Role.role;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class PoliciesTest {

  @Test
  public void streamImplementation_whenComparedWithALoopImplementation_thenShouldReturnTheSameResult() {
    final String userId = "user-1";
    final Role role1 = role("role-1", "user-1", "user-2");
    final Role role2 = role("role-2", "user-1", "user-3");
    final Role role3 = role("role-3", "user-2", "user-3");
    final Role role4 = role("role-4", "user-3", "user-4");
    final List<Policy> allowedPoliciesThisCustomer = asList(
      policy(role1, role2),
      policy(role3, role4)
    );
    final Set<String> oldResult = loopImplementation(userId, allowedPoliciesThisCustomer);
    final Set<String> newResult = streamImplementation(userId, allowedPoliciesThisCustomer);

    assertThat(newResult).isEqualTo(oldResult);
  }

  private static Set<String> streamImplementation(final String userId, final List<Policy> allowedPoliciesThisCustomer) {
    return allowedPoliciesThisCustomer.stream()
      .map(Policy::getRoles)
      .map(Map::values)
      .flatMap(Collection::stream)
      .filter(r -> r.getUsers().contains(userId))
      .map(Role::getRoleName)
      .collect(toSet());
  }

  private static Set<String> loopImplementation(final String userId, final List<Policy> allowedPoliciesThisCustomer) {
    final Set<String> allowedRolesThisUser = new HashSet<>();

    for (final Policy policy : allowedPoliciesThisCustomer) {
      final Map<String, Role> roles = policy.getRoles();
      for (final Role role : roles.values()) {
        if (role.getUsers().contains(userId)) {
          allowedRolesThisUser.add(role.getRoleName());
        }
      }
    }

    return allowedRolesThisUser;
  }
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
class Policy {
  private final Map<String, Role> roles;

  static Policy policy(final Role... roles) {
    final Map<String, Role> rolesMap = stream(roles)
      .collect(toMap(Role::getRoleName, identity()));

    return new Policy(rolesMap);
  }
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
class Role {
  private final List<String> users;
  private final String roleName;

  static Role role(final String roleName, final String... users) {
    return new Role(asList(users), roleName);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
private Set<String> getAllowRolesFromInheritedPolicy(String userId, List<Policy> allowedPoliciesThisCustomer) {
    return allowedPoliciesThisCustomer.stream()
        .flatMap(policy -> policy.getRoles().values().stream())
        .filter(role -> role.getUsers().contains(userId))
        .map(Role::getRoleName)
        .collect(Sets::newHashSet, (set, e) -> set.add(e), (a, b) -> a.addAll(b));
}
```

Comment: Would either Collectors::toSet or (HashSet::new, Set::add, Set::addAll) suffice for the collection step(i.e. Stream::collect)? I want to know what advantage does Guava's Sets::newHashSet has over the aforementioned alternatives.

Comment: Generally, you might want to avoid the dot notations inside map methods and split them out into multiple lines for readability. From a performance standpoint, it doesn't make as much of a difference but readability and type inference in readability goes up quite a bit #opinion :)

Comment: Also, using the inbuilt Collectors.toSet seems easier than manually building a collector to collect a set :)

Comment: @JAnderton OP may expect the resulting set to be mutable, which isn't guaranteed by `Collectors.toSet()`. You can still use the equivalent but cleaner `Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new)`.

Comment: @shmosel good point! Didn't think of that. I generally prefer writing non-mutating code and hence the implementation. If I need to mutate it (lets say by adding something), I'd wrap the result of the method into a `new HashSet<>(result)`.

Comment: @JAnderton That seems a little wasteful given the straightforward alternative.

Comment: @shmosel: Even then, there’s still no advantage of `Sets::newHashSet` over `HashSet::new`. These factory methods had a use in Java 5 and Java 6, when there was no type inference for constructor invocation, but for method invocation, but since Java 7, they are obsolete. — oh well, [I just looked them up](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#newHashSet--) and their documentation even says it…

Comment: @Holger Indeed, that's why I suggested `HashSet::new`.

Comment: @shmosel: right, you have shown a viable alternative, I just wanted to mention that [srborlongan’s question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093071/error-when-trying-to-convert-nested-for-loop-to-java-8-streams/45093211?noredirect=1#comment77159334_45093211) has not fully answered yet. Interestingly, the questioner used `Collectors.toList()`, which isn’t suitable to get a `Set`, but doesn’t indicate that a mutable set is required. Just changing it to `Collectors.toSet()` would be the straight-forward answer.

Comment: @Holger Well, he's passing the list into a new set, so it's technically valid, if somewhat convoluted (though not much more so than an [earlier suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45093071/error-when-trying-to-convert-nested-for-loop-to-java-8-streams/45093211?noredirect=1#comment77159581_45093211)). The only real problem with OP's code is that it's not flat mapping.

Comment: @shmosel: I see